# Python: array of 2 dim shape (1,1024) is read as 3 dim array

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

In python, I have a list a of arrays, each of shape (1, 1024) and a list b of ints {1,0,0,1…]
Now I want to train a basic SVM with that. 
I always receive this error message:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

But doesnt the shape tell me, that I have a 2 Dim shape?
There is probably something wrong with my array but I don`t understand, what.
I am glad for any help.

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(lista, listb)
```

First 10 items of the array:

```
[array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ..., -0.03608917,
         0.06382023,  0.02493868]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ..., -0.00363029,
         0.04429551,  0.04517733]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ..., -0.01848865,
         0.03857033, -0.04184096]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ..., -0.00812042,
        -0.01121382, -0.07293765]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ...,  0.0026521 ,
        -0.00911874,  0.02558753]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ...,  0.0128456 ,
        -0.00659914, -0.05465406]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ..., -0.00801555,
        -0.06554729, -0.04112517]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ...,  0.0015485 ,
        -0.03974668,  0.03871798]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ...,  0.03571296,
         0.0097717 , -0.02939025]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.00381735, -0.02317988, -0.06664753, ..., -0.00178309,
        -0.00751928, -0.00501447]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: reshape your array with (n_rows, n_dims), and go for arrays instead of lists, they tend to perform better with scikit learn estimators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think this way:

`[(1, 1024),(1, 1024),(1, 1024)...(1, 1024)]`

to select a single element here you will need 3 things: position in the list, the n in (n, 1024) and k in (1, k). This is a 3 dimensional data structure.

use `np.stack`  or convert your list with `np.array` and  `np.reshape(len(list),1024)`. This way you`ll have a unique array of shape (n, 1024).